# Not able to run local site and api at the same time laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api

I am not able to run local site and api at the same time laravel i am running the local site in port: 8000
and i am also using same port for api but its not working. I am using Xampp on windows.
Api url : http://localhost:8000/api/v1/login in postman works. But when in try in website with http client its not working

Comment: Ports cannot be reused, each process has to have it's own port

Answer (score 2):

The same port can be used only if you use a different domain for the API. For example, you can use webapp.com for the frontend and use api.webapp.com for the API.

Comment: how do you do this locally?